# Spring batch java.io.IOException: Stream closed error

Tags: spring-batch

I have 10 text file those containing xmls that I wanted to insert into database. Each file size is around 113 MB. After reading 5-6 files I am getting " java.io.IOException: Stream closed " error. Below is my Spring batch configuration. Can you please suggest me how do I correct this issue.

```
<bean id="gimReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="delegate">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
                <property name="lineMapper">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                        <property name="lineTokenizer">
                            <bean
                                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                                <property name="names" value="gimDataStr" />
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                            <bean
                                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                                <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="gimDataBean" />
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="resources" value="file:C:/Vet/XMLtype/SampleData/*.sql" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="gimDataBean" class="com.jpmorgan.batch.standinginstruction.model.GimDataBean" scope="prototype"/>

    <bean id="jdbcWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
        </property>
        <property name="sql" value="INSERT INTO GIMDATA (GIM_DATA) VALUES(:gimDataStr)" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

<batch:job id="gimId">
        <batch:step id="import">
            <batch:tasklet task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="20">
                <batch:chunk reader="gimReader" writer="jdbcWriter"
                    commit-interval="500">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="simpleTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
        <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="20" />
    </bean>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Do I have to use partition here to insert the data from all the files into database?

Below is the complete error that I am getting.

```
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:219)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.readNextItem(MultiResourceItemReader.java:119)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.read(MultiResourceItemReader.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy25.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:258)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:229)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:292)
```

Thanks
Sach

Answer (score 0):

you are using a [multi-threaded step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) with a stateful(1) reader (multiresourceitemreader), for your usecase you could go with [partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) and use the [multiresourcepartitioner](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/MultiResourcePartitioner.html)

1) from spring batch multi-threaded step:

> There are some practical limitations of using multi-threaded Steps for
>   some common Batch use cases. Many participants in a Step (e.g. readers
>   and writers) are stateful, and if the state is not segregated by
>   thread, then those components are not usable in a multi-threaded Step.
>   In particular most of the off-the-shelf readers and writers from
>   Spring Batch are not designed for multi-threaded use.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Using partition I can able to load 700,000 records in around 3 minutes. Is there anyway I could still improve the timings? My partition grid-size is 20 and commit-interval is 2000. I am using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.

Comment: try batch inserts (or bulk insert), raise database-connection count (combined with pooling)

Comment: I did raise database connection to 50. I have set commit interval to 2000 that means every after 2000 records data get committed in database, so that is working as buld insert I believe.

Comment: the jdbcbatchitemwriter already utilizes the jdbc batch api, try to profile to find more bottlenecks, i would remove the reflection heavy BeanWrapperFieldsetMapper

Comment: I am using jdbcbatchitemwriter for database insertion. Is there any alternative for BeanWrapperFieldsetMapper?

Comment: Implement the Mapper by yourself 

Comment: Thanks Michael. Let me try that.